# Drawing d3 charts without svg

Tags: canvas, d3.js, svg

Is it possible to draw d3 chart without using svg (purely canvas)?
SVG has an issue in Firefox as explained in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22875328/why-is-this-animation-so-slow-in-firefox?rq=1). I was using nvd3 to make a horizontal bar chart and I know nvd3 always use `<svg></svg>`.

I never try drawing using d3 directly, but based on the example [here](http://bl.ocks.org/kiranml1/6872226), it uses canvas element but still uses `svg` as well under it.

Does D3 always use `svg` element? I am new to D3 so any feedback is welcomed. Thanks.

Comment: Even in your second example, it does not use the `<canvas>` tags! Afaik d3 has to use some markup language for the elements, hence canvas is not possible.

Comment: No. `d3` is entirely designed around SVG. Although you can use canvas to draw most things that SVG can draw, you would have to edit almost all the `d3` code to convert it to use html5 canvas.

Comment: @markE Not exactly. Some charts are build out of just HTML elements. It just needs a markup language to work upon.

Comment: @Sirko, Agreed, the magic of d3 involves manipulating html both SVG & non-SVG elements using some amazing math+logic. I guess my point is that I don't see an easy path to "snap out" SVG and "snap in" html5 Canvas. That's my 2-cents. :-)

Comment: Google brings up some good examples to start with: [Canvas Parallel Coordinates](http://bl.ocks.org/syntagmatic/2409451), [DOM-to-Canvas using D3](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1276463)

Comment: @markE thanks! I think at this point I believe the answer is it's possible but might be tricky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example is not using canvas. It has just used a variable named canvas to refer to the outer div.

```
var canvas = d3.select('#wrapper')
```

It is just about possible to use d3 with canvas, but highly irregular, and pretty far removed from the intention of d3 which is in essence, a specialised data to graphic dom manipulation library.

n.b. an article about using d3 with canvas: https://bocoup.com/weblog/d3js-and-canvas/

Comment: thank you. so silly just because of the variable names I thought of that.